# How to echo a hyperlink in php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am reading emails from database. And i want to echo the emails as hyperlink, but its not working.

```
<?php
$un = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

// connect to the db
$user = 'proc';
$pswd = 'passwd';
$db = 'school';
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

// run the query to search for the username and password the match
$query = "SELECT email AS text FROM contact";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());

// this is where the actual verification happens
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ("\n".$row['text']);
    echo "<a href=.$row['text']>some text</a>";
}
?>
```

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot embed variables in doubly-quoted strings like that in all cases. [Here's what you *can* do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
echo "<a href={$row['text']}>some text</a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href=".$row['text'].">some text</a>";
```

Personally I prefer the second form because it has historically been easier to see at a glance that a variable is being embedded through your editor's syntax highlighting (although today editors might also highlight the first form).

Be aware that **your current code has other problems:** no quotes around HTML attribute values, and not properly escaping values that get embedded in HTML. Fix that as well with something like

```
echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row['text']).'">some text</a>";
```

The exact correct form depends on the encoding of your data as well; see [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for the details.

Comment: this is somewhat invalid HTML :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your echo statement:

```
echo "<a href=\"mailto:$row[text]\" >some text</a>";
```

Comment: you failed. what does a dot doing here?

Answer (score 1):

As per the code snippet I suppose it is going wrong at the line :

```
echo "<a href=.$row['text']>some text</a>";
```

It should be :

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $row['text'] . "\">some text</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way

```
echo "<a href='$row[text]'>some text</a>";
```

However, my favorite would be to get the data first

```
<?php
include 'my_super_db_access_abstraction_class.php';
$data['rows'] = db::getAll("SELECT email AS text FROM contact");
tpl('template.php',$data);
?>
```

and then include a template with natural looking HTML:

```
<ul?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
  <li><a href="<?=$row['text']?>">some text</a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```
$text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})','<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $row['text']);
echo $text;
```